Подскажите, как закруглить края у серой обёртки вокруг кнопки?
Не могу найти способ закругления фона вокруг кнопки справа внизу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

border-radius?

при исходной публикации изображение сбросилось. один border-radius тут не поможет, по-моему(

Как-то так можна реализовать.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

section {
  padding-block: min(20vh, 2rem);
  width: calc(min(76.5rem, 90%));
  margin-inline: auto;
  color: #111;
}

section a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section .container {
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(16rem, 1fr));
  gap: 2rem;
}

section .container .card:nth-child(1) .box .icon .iconBox {
  background: #d3b19a;
}

section .container .card:nth-child(2) .box .icon .iconBox {
  background: #70b3b1;
}

section .container .card:nth-child(3) .box .icon .iconBox {
  background: #d05fa2;
}

section .container .card ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.625rem;
}

section .container .card ul li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: var(--clr-tag);
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.625rem;
  border-radius: 0.188rem;
}

section .container .card ul .branding {
  color: #704a31;
}

section .container .card ul .packaging {
  color: #1e3938;
}

section .container .card ul .marketing {
  color: #4d1637;
}

section .container .card .content {
  padding: 0.938rem 0.625rem;
}

section .container .card .content h3 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 1.3909rem + 0.4364vw, 1.8rem);
}

section .container .card .content p {
  margin: 0.625rem 0 1.25rem;
  color: #565656;
}

section .container .card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: 18.75rem;
  background: var(--clr);
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section .container .card-inner .box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .imgBox {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .imgBox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.375rem;
  right: -0.375rem;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background: var(--clr);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon:hover .iconBox {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0.375rem;
  left: -1.25rem;
  background: transparent;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0.313rem 0.313rem 0 0.313rem #fff;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -1.25rem;
  right: 0.375rem;
  background: transparent;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0.313rem 0.313rem 0 0.313rem var(--clr);
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon .iconBox {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0.625rem;
  background: #282828;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

section .container .card-inner .box .icon .iconBox span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-inner" style="--clr:#fff;">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601049676869-702ea24cfd58?q=80&w=2073&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="Trust & Co.">
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <a href="#" class="iconBox"> <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
              </span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>trust &amp; co.</h3>
        <p>Fill out the form and the algorithm will offer the right team of experts</p>
        <ul>
          <li style="--clr-tag:#d3b19a;" class="branding">branding</li>
          <li style="--clr-tag:#70b3b1;" class="packaging">packaging</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



Пример, не мой, но концепция думаю понятна. Правда в твоем случаи ещё с тенями будут заморочки.

с ума сойти. спасибо!

Скругления вокруг кнопки могут потребовать немало кода и подгонки. А ещё и тени для объёма... Да и масштабировать это позже будет затруднительно. Думаю, что наилучшим решением здесь будет использование растровой или векторной картинки.
Если картинку вставлять через тег <img> или css-свойство background, то результат будет, мягко говоря, не очень, так как при любых значениях object-fit или background-size и масштабировании, изображение будет либо обрезаться, либо менять свои пропорции.
Но, выход есть! Можно задействовать довольно редко используемое свойство border-image и специально подготовленную картинку.


.image { position: relative; /* Only for example --> */ display: inline-grid; place-items: start center; min-height: 120px; max-height: 90vh; min-width: 120px; max-width: 90vw; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #00f; overflow: hidden; resize: both; }
.background { background: url('https://i.sstatic.net/6HWZR1PB.png') 0 0 / 100% 100% no-repeat; }
.border { border-image: url('https://i.sstatic.net/6HWZR1PB.png') 30% 65% 65% 30% fill / auto repeat; }

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px; right: 4px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  border: none; border-radius: 100vmax;
  font: 28px/1em sans-serif;
  color: #fff; background: #025790;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover { transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 1turn); }
<div class="background image">background<button>&#129125;</button></div>
<div class="border image">border<button>&#129125;</button></div>



Более подробно про свойство border-image можно почитать здесь.
